# How can I make a program close after 3 wrong user/password attempts

Tags: c#

For a program I'm making I'm required to implement a feature that allows the user 3 attempts to enter the correct Username and Password, however I'm having trouble closing the program after 3 incorrect attempts.

I understand a counter with every wrong attempt is the way to do this, but I can't for the life of me figure out why every attempt I've tried hasn't worked and resulted in the program closing after 3 wrong attempts.

I feel really stupid because I know it's right in front of me how to do it, I am still a beginner though so I was expecting to mess up on something like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string stringUser = "User";
    string stringPass = "Password";
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 3)
    {
        if (textBoxUsername.Text != stringUser && 
            textBoxPassword.Text != stringPass)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to exit from the program? There are a bunch of problems with your code. 

1. There is nothing that would cause the program to exit. 
2. You reset `i` to `0` every time you call the function. In fact, `i` doesn't exist outside the function.
3. Check your `if` condition. Build a truth table if you are confused. `textBoxUsername.Text != stringUser && textBoxPassword.Text != stringPass` will only be `true` when _both_ are unequal. You want to look for the case when _either_ is unequal.

Comment: 4. `while (i < 3)` is the wrong condition to check for. Once you click on the button, its handler is executed without giving the user the chance to change their input, so `i` gets incremented to 3 instantly when the `if` condition is entered (remember that it's the wrong condition anyway).
5. When the `if` condition _isn't_ entered, `i` is never incremented, so you enter an infinite loop

Comment: Sorry I should have said I've been completely rearranging things to test and this was just the most recent copy/paste of what I have. I had another if statement for if counter > max attempts, close(); but still nothing was happening. I think it is like you said I'm resetting the counter but I couldn't wrap my head around how not to do that

Comment: Obviously, your code is terrible; but let's put this aside for a moment. In order to do what you want you need to maintain the number of attempts **outside** this function. What framework are you using? WPF? Windows Forms? Legacy ASP.NET WebForms? Second, what do you mean *close*? when the user clicks 3 times - what do you expect program to do?

Comment: Windows Forms, and yeah I should have made it clearer: The program is expected to automatically close on more than 3 incorrect attempts.

Comment: But why though? what problem is this "feature" trying to solve? How is the user going to react when they encounter this "feature"? Are you going to prevent the user from immediately launching the app again? Sometimes the right answer is not to implement it.

Comment: Yeah. Unless you remember somehow - in a non manipulative fashion - all the user has to do is restart the program. This is simple as heck to program in a UI test. Now, if you cache i.e. an API access token and delete it after 3 login attempts - THAT is HARDER (not hard) to undo (and still trivial with disc imaging technology). Achievement: NOTHING.

Comment: I do wish I could go more in depth on this. It's for a college assignment so I have to do exactly what the brief says apart from some added functionality - but even that must stay within limits of what's being asked. Hoping to be on a CS degree this time next year so I'm just really trying to excel in the programming and maths specifically as a good foundation for what comes next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting the `int i` with each button click. Move it outside of the function so it doesn't get reset.

```
int attempts = 0;
string stringUser = "User";
string stringPass = "Password";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (i >= 3){
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
    
    if (textBoxUsername.Text != stringUser && textBoxPassword.Text != stringPass)
    {
        i++;
    } 
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull");
    }
}
```